# Catching "play video" event in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

in my Android app I have a `WebView` with basic browsing functionality. My problem is that I want to get notified somehow if the user starts playing a flash video. I tried to set a `WebViewClient` on my webView, and monitor the URLs in the `onLoadResource` method, but it doesn't work. My question is the following: is it possible to catch an event of this kind, and if yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Flash video or HTML5 video?

Comment: Mainly flash :) The HTML5 video is not a problem, but many of the sites still use flash.

Comment: It will be possible to find a way of doing it with HTML5, but I cannot think a workaround for flash.

Answer (score 1):

wv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        WebView.HitTestResult hr = ((WebView)v).getHitTestResult();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Would it not be possible to detect tapping on video play button by html element ID? In the onTouchListener

How is the video displayed? instant play or a button to begin playback?

Comment: There is a button to begin playback

Comment: Then simply use the above to handle the onclick event of your play button!

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. the hr variable returned null for getExtra() and 0 for getType()